# Big O Notation: Using multiple forloops within Django template VS multiple queries using a filter in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

This is a specific question based on an attempt to increase performance speeds when querying data.

So I was trying to figure out within a Django template itself, how to break a conditional on the first attempt. It seems that it is not possible, and the suggestions were all to use the *views.py* for the logic instead. This led me to try filtering based on a condition being met.

In my example, I have two scenarios that I'm comparing.

---

(1) In the first one, I have one query inside my *views.py* to get all items. Naturally, Item is a schema I have in my models. Anyway, inside the template I want to render, I have the context being passed and have 11 separate forloops all iterating over the same all_items loop. Then based on the condition (ie item.category), the appropriate html is rendered.

Again, what I wanted to do was have 1 loop, and then based on the condition, render to the appropriate places, but **only go through that all_items loop once**. Unfortunately, I'm not able to break the loop in the template after the condition to not over-render html I don't want on each successive iteration.

So this led me the next scenario:

---

(2) In my views I created 11 separate queries **(eg item.objects.filter(category='1'), item.objects.filter(category='2', etc.)**. I in turn assign each one of those to 11 separate variables passed through my views as context to render in the template. This also allows me to remove the conditional in the template where I check for the category.

---

What I'm wondering is, in the latter example, is each query filter the same as running the same forloop for all_items in the template, just done a little differently? Am I saving any time with the latter? It is hard to say just based on my user experience, so any insights would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Item` model containing `category` and `name` field you can use `values()` and single query with `filter()` as:

```
categories = ['1', '2', ... '11']

items = item.objects.filter(category__in=categories).values('category','name')
```

What you have in output is:

```
<QuerySet [{'category': '1', 'name': 'name1'}, {'category': 2, 'name': 'name2'}, ..., {'category': '11', 'name': 'name11'}]>
```

You can loop `items` result without all those separate database queries.

Please comment in case of any questions.

P.S. I used `name` field as an example, it could be any field presented in your model.